# Stuck on an alternative proof of DeMorgan's Laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing Elementary Topology and I came across this result which the professor took it on face value.

If $X$ is the universal set, and $J$ is any index set then, $X\setminus \bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}=\bigcup_{\gamma \in J}(X\setminus A_{\gamma})$. I checked my notes on proofs of DeMorgan's Law from my earlier courses and they seem to prove this result $(\bigcup_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma})^C=\bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}^C$ and say to prove the first result replace $A_{\gamma}$ by $A_{\gamma}^C$ and then take a complement. I understand the way of that approach but I want to do an element wise proof for this as well. This is how far I have got:

Let $x \in X\setminus \bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}$

$\implies x\notin\bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}$

What should be next?

Comment: If $x$ is *not* in *every* $A_\gamma$, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in X$, we have
\begin{align*}
&
x \in X\setminus \bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
x\notin\bigcap_{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
x\not\in A_{\gamma}\;\text{for some}\;\gamma\in J
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
x\in X{\setminus}A_{\gamma}\;\text{for some}\;\gamma\in J
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
x\in\bigcup_{\gamma \in J}(X{\setminus}A_{\gamma})
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: @Ted Shifrin If $x \notin \bigcap _{\gamma \in J}A_{\gamma}$ then how can we conclude that $x$ is not in some $A_{\gamma}$. Consider for example two sets, $A_1$ and $A_2$, if $y \notin A_1 \bigcap A_2$ doesn't mean that $y$ is not in $A_1$ or not in $A_2$

Comment: @Karan Kumar: If $y \notin A_1 \cap A_2$, then $y$ can't be in _both_ $A_1$ and $A_2$, so that _does_ mean that ($y$ is not in $A_1$) or ($y$ is not in $A_2$).

Comment: Thanks. This helps. @quasi